# When I clone my github project it doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

Using a Flask API on a ReactJs website, I have 2 routes on my server.py file.

On the frontend I can upload a file to firebase storage. In server.py, I have a route that uses POSTed information about the filename after it's uploaded, then downloads it from firebase.

```
# File download Link
@app.route('/filePath', methods=['POST'])
def get_path():
    data = request.get_json()["path"]
    storage.child(f"files/{data}").download(f"files/Resume.pdf")
    return "Success.."
```

Then I have another route that does some logic with the file after it's been downloaded. The route then feeds the information to the frontend as such

```
# Details API Get Route
@app.route("/details")
def details():
    path = r"path\to\pdf"
    person_data = PersonAnalyser(path).get_data()
    return {"email":person_data.get('email'),
            "mobile_number":person_data.get('mobile_number'),
            "name":person_data.get('name'),
    }
```

My issue, is that the /details route is executed everytime the page loads up, before I can even upload a file. I'm not sure how I can change that.

Here's how I'm calling it on the frontend

```
const FileUpload = () => {
    const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([{}])
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const formHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      uploadFiles(file);
      update();
    };

    const update = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details').then((res) => {
        setInitialData(res.data);
      });
    };

    useEffect(update, []);
```

I'm not sure if the rest is relevant or not so I'll just post it, This is the entire FileUpload which I'm exporting and calling in App.jsx

```
const FileUpload = () => {
    const [initialData, setInitialData] = useState([{}])
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const formHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      uploadFiles(file);
      update();
    };

    const update = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details').then((res) => {
        setInitialData(res.data);
      });
    };

    useEffect(update, []);
  
    const uploadFiles = (file) => {
      //
      if (!file) return;
      if (!initialData) return null;
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
  
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const prog = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          setProgress(prog);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error),
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(() => {
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/filePath', {
              'path': file.name
            }).then(() => console.log(file.name));
          });
        }
      );
    };

    

    return (
        <>
            <div className="file-card">

                <div className="file-inputs">
                    <input type="file" onChange={formHandler} />
                    <button>
                        <i>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
                        </i>
                        Upload
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ProgressBar color={"#ff7979"} width={"150px"} value={Math.round(progress)} max={100} />
                <p className="main">Supported files</p>
                <p className="info">PDF, JPG, PNG</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3>Hello {initialData.name}</h3>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default FileUpload
```

Just to re-iterate, my problem is that `/details` is executed when the page loads which throws off the entire workflow. It needs to wait for `/filePath` to be called and finish executing to then start executing `/details`. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line is causing `update()` to run on page load. If you don't want that then remove it:

```
useEffect(update, []);
```

To run it on `/filePath` complete, then I'd suggest the `.then()` for that axios call:

```
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/filePath', {
          'path': file.name
        }).then(() => {
          console.log(file.name);
          update();
        });
```

In the `formHandler`, you are immediately calling `update()` after `uploadFiles()`:

```
const formHandler = (e) => {
  ...
  uploadFiles(file);
  update();
};
```

This is a problem because `uploadFiles()` is async, meaning `update()` will run before `uploadFiles()` completes. If you move `update()` to the `.then()` as suggested above, then you can remove it from `formHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I used useEffect(update, []); because I want to fetch information everytime I upload without having to refresh after every upload. I'm not sure if you're following me

Comment: Your way works but there's a slight issue, it's double fetching, it is only called after I upload, but it executes before i download the file and it overwrites the previous file, So now it's getting information once on the previous file before its overwritten by the new file and once again after the new file is downloaded.